# Замена функции высшего порядка на рекурсию + lambda

Tags: python, функции, рекурсия, lambda

Никак не могу понять как заменить функцию высшего порядка **fn(f, n)**, используемую при вычислении sin (sin (sin (sin (sin (1))))) = 0,587181

```
from math import sin


def fn(f, n):
    def fn_inside(x):
        for i in range(n):
            x = f(x)
        return x
    return fn_inside


f1 = fn(lambda x: "sin(%s)" % x, 5)
f2 = fn(lambda x: sin(x), 5)
print("%s = %f" % (f1("1"), f2(1)))
print(fn(lambda x: sin(x), 0)(1000))
```

на **рекурсию + lambda**

**Обновление**:
Еще должно работать с выражением

```
print(fn(lambda x: sin(x), 0)(1000))
```

**Ответ** выглядит примерно так

```
def fn(f, n):
    if n < 1:
        return lambda y: y
    elif n == 1:
        return f
    else:
        return lambda y: fn(f, n-1)(f(y))
```

Comment: А можно для тупых повторить?)

Comment: Implement the function fn(f, n) using recursion+lambdas  =)

Comment: "эта функция будет использоваться еще много где в коде" - если речь о рабочем коде, а не учебном, то лучше не используйте рекурсию! Нет никакой гарантии, что вы не выйдете за допустимую глубину рекурсии на конкретной конфигурации, где вы будете запускать код. Она может быть разной и не везде она может регулироваться в широких пределах. Рекурсию на питоне лучше не использовать в "боевых" целях от слова совсем.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо. Я так и понял. Просто изначально мне казалось, что код удасться "упаковать" во что-то короткое. Однако, по итогу получилось шило на мыло без выигрыша в чем-либо.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужен рекурсивный синус, то можно все в одну `lambda` засунуть:

```
from math import sin

sin_rec = lambda x, n: x if n == 0 else sin(sin_rec(x, n - 1))
print(sin_rec(1, 5))  # 0.5871809965734309
```

Либо с подстановкой метода:

```
from math import sin

func = lambda fn, n: lambda x: fn(x) if n == 1 else fn(func(fn, n - 1)(x))

print(func(sin, 5)(1))  # 0.5871809965734309
```

Comment: эта функция будет использоваться еще много где в коде. Тут важа именно универсальность.

Comment: у меня почему-то ругается на RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison

Comment: Что ругается? Пример можно?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Habar\test site\1.py", line 3, in <module>
    print(fn_rec(sin, 1, 1000))
  File "E:\Habar\test site\1.py", line 2, in <lambda>
    fn_rec = lambda fn, x, n: x if n == 0 else fn(fn_rec(fn, x, n - 1))
  File "E:\Habar\test site\1.py", line 2, in <lambda>
    fn_rec = lambda fn, x, n: x if n == 0 else fn(fn_rec(fn, x, n - 1))
  File "E:\Habar\test site\1.py", line 2, in <lambda>
    fn_rec = lambda fn, x, n: x if n == 0 else fn(fn_rec(fn, x, n - 1))
  [Previous line repeated 996 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth....

Comment: я просто запустил код у себя в отдельном окне

Comment: `import sys` потом `sys.setrecursionlimit(n)`, где устанавливаете максимальную глубину рекурсии

Comment: Проверить глубину можно через `print(sys.getrecursionlimit())`

Comment: Спасибо, лимит побежден. Однако, если подставить в оригинальную конструкцию `print(fn_rec(lambda x: sin(x), 0)(1000))` то выдает TypeError: <lambda>() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

Comment: У меня другой формат входных данных. Он выше в ответе приведен. В Вашем случае он будет, наверное, так выглядеть `fn_rec(sin, 0, 1000)`

Comment: Обновил код последнего блока теперь подается в него функция с числом повторений и аргументами в виде `func(sin, n)(arg)`

Answer (score 0):

Видимо как-то так:

```
from math import sin

def fn(f, n):
    return f if n == 1 else lambda y: fn(f, n-1)(f(y))

f1 = fn(lambda x: sin(x), 5)
print(f1(1))

import sys 
sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)
print(fn(lambda x: sin(x), 1000)(0))
```

Comment: если применить к `print(fn(lambda x: sin(x), 0)(1000))` то ругается на RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded in comparison, а так работает

Comment: @Skeptic_0286 Ну так правильно ругается. У Питона рекурсия не бесконечная, и по умолчанию глубина рекурсии 1000.

Comment: проблема в том, что почему-то `import sys` и 
`sys.setrecursionlimit(1500)` ничего не меняет

Comment: @Skeptic_0286 Меняет, если вызывать функцию правильно - `print(fn(lambda x: sin(x), 1000)(0))`. Количество итераций - сначала, значение для функции - в последних скобках. При вашей записи рекурсия начинается с 0 и уходит в минус бесконечность.

Comment: Спасибо, однако, в вашем случае же и результат другой: функция вместо 1000 вернет 0.